# How to start a watch process for a bash script that sends notifications? (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, process, bash-scripting

I have written a bash script that monitors the output of `sensors`  and uses `notify-send` to alert me when my notebook is overheating.
I start the script with `watch -n 15 fullscriptname`
and also added this line to `/etc/rc.local`

It works as it should when I start it from the terminal and the process is also running after startup. However then the notifications don't show up. I assume it is because rc.local is executed by root.

(I also tried to add it to Startup Applications via Unity, but this also doesn't work).

So my questions: Is there a way to start a process as a user? What is the proper way for automatically starting such a script (which configuration files do I use)?

Comment: You can use `su` to execute a command as a different user, but for your use case, terdon's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be have `cron` start it. Run `crontab -e` that should open your crontab in your default editor, add this line to it, save and close it:

```
@reboot watch -n 15 /path/to/script
```

Another option would be adding `watch -n 15 /path/to/script` to your `~/.Xsession` file but I'm not sure if Ubuntu still loads that.

Comment: hm, I got the watch process now running with the correct user (after setting TERM=dumb cron is no longer sending an error mail). But somehow the notifications don't reach my desktop. Anyways, thanks for the hint with crontab

Comment: @ndldd capture any errors produced by the cron: `@reboot watch -n 15 /path/to/script 2>/tmp/error`. That way you can see what is wrong.

Comment: I installed postfix for localmail and I got an Email from Cron:  'Error opening terminal: unknown.' but I think I fixed this now as I'm no longer getting error mails and the process runs. The problem is now with the script itself if I run it manually in the background by appending '&' the notifications are also not shown.

edit: Just found a possible solution:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6167/i-finally-found-out-how-to-use-notify-send-with-at-or-cron

Comment: Yes, I got it finally working, thanks for the help, I added 
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    DISPLAY=:0.0
    XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
    TERM=dumb
above the crontab line.